# How can I get $\sin{(\frac{1}{x})}$ to always be positive?

Tags: real-analysis

So if I have a function for all positive values of $x$: 
$$
g(x) = \cases{-x \sin (\frac{1}{x}) & if $x \neq 0$\\ 0 & otherwise}
$$
Is there a way I can alter the equation to make $g(x)$ positive by adding a power on $x$? Like for example, $(-1) x^b \sin (\frac{1}{x})$

I don't think it's possible since I looked at the graph of $\sin (\frac{1}{x})$ and $x \sin x$ online and those graphs were bounded by $-1$ and $1$.

Can someone please give me a proof or disproof of this theory? I'm sorry if it's vaguely worded.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? $\sin^2(1/x)$ will be non-negative for example... Or perhaps  $x^2\cdot\sin^2(1/x)$ it can be continuously extended to $0$ also

Comment: Basically, I want a c for which  (-1) (x^c) sin (1/x) is always positive

Comment: $x\sin(1/x) + x$ is non-negative as well. Also, I edited your post to look better, can you please verify that it's correct? Please use [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in the future for writing mathematics expressions.

Comment: This is not possible, since the change in the sign of the function comes from the factor $\sin(1/x)$. Why don't you tell us why you need such a function?

Answer (score 1):

No, there will be no factor $\pm 1 x^i $ that makes it positive since $\sin (1/x) $ is alternating. So this would imply to find a polynomial with this alternating character, and thus a infinite number of roots. However it may be possible to find a infinite series expansion that does the job